# ¿Por qué no me deja introducir datos en la pila?

Tags: c, stack

Estoy aprendiendo estructuras de datos en c y de paso aprendiendo a usar los punteros (y asignación dinámica de memoria cuando le pille el tranquilo a los punteros). He empezado por un stack simple pero no entiendo por que, cuando intento introducir un elemento en el stack el programa simplemente termina. Supongo que este haciendo algo mal con el puntero pero no se que.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define max 10

struct stack{
    int elemento[max];
};

typedef struct stack st;

int crearstack(st *puntero){
    puntero->elemento[0];
}

int pintastack(int posicion,st *puntero){
    int contador;
    if(posicion==0){
        printf("stack vacio \n");
    }
    else{
        for(contador=0;contador<=posicion;contador++){
            printf("Objeto %i: %i \n",posicion,puntero->elemento[posicion]);
            }
    }
}

int introduce(int posicion,st *puntero){
    int nelemento;
    if(posicion<max){
        printf("\n Introduce nuevo elemento: ");
        scanf("%i",&nelemento);
        printf("eco \n");
        puntero->elemento[posicion]=nelemento;
        printf("ecoo \n");
        posicion++;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Stack lleno \n");
    }
}

int eliminar(int posicion,st *puntero){
    if(posicion>1){
        printf("\n Eliminando elemento \n");
        posicion--;
        puntero->elemento[posicion]=0;
        //free(puntero);
        printf("Elemento eliminado \n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Stack vacio \n");
    }
}

int main(){
    st *puntero;
    int accion, posicion=0;
    //crear stack
    crearstack(puntero);
    //Pedir accion
    while(accion!=4){
    printf("Lista de opciones: \n");
    printf("Mostrar stack (1) \n");
    printf("Introducir elemento (2) \n)");
    printf("Eliminar elemento (3) \n");
    printf("Terminar programa (4) \n");

    printf("Seleccione accion: ");
    scanf("%i",&accion);
    switch(accion){
        case 1:
            pintastack(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 2:
            introduce(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 3:
            eliminar(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("Terminando programa");
        break;
        default:
            ("\n Orden no reconocida");
        }
        printf("accion: %i \n",accion);
    }

    printf("Programa terminado");
}
```

Me gustaría saber que es lo que hago mal exactamente, entiendo el concepto de puntero pero me cuesta entender  como funcionan a veces.

Comment: Saludos. El programa termina; ¿es con mensaje de error o vez mensaje *Programa terminado*? Te comento que tu código sin importar que pongas no se repite, no hay bucle.

Comment: Muy buenas, el programa termina sin errores. Quizá debí haber sido más especifico, cuando intento introducir un dato, pinta el "eco" pero no el "ecoo", y termina el programa.

Comment: Tu definición de stack falta una característica importante, el tamaño actual, o la posisión de la elemento superior. Intenta compensarlo introduciendo el tamaño actual en otra parte, `posicion`. No funcionará bien. La posición debe estar adentro de `struct stack`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```c
st *puntero;
int accion, posicion=0;
//crear stack
crearstack(puntero);
```

El puntero en ningún momento apunta a un bloque de memoria que le pertenece al programa, ya que la función `crearstack` tampoco le asigna nada al puntero, por ende, queda apuntando a una zona inaccesible.

**Solución:** Se debe reservar memoria con duración automática (se crea cuando la función se ejecute y se destruye cuando termina su ejecución) y asignar la dirección base al puntero:

```c
int main()
{
    int accion, posicion=0;
    /*
       Esto crea un bloque de memoria alojado en la pila de llamada y le asigna la dirección de 
       memoria del primer elemento de la estructura en la variable llamada "puntero".
    */
    st myStack;
    st *puntero = &myStack;
    while(accion!=4){
    printf("Lista de opciones: \n");
    printf("Mostrar stack (1) \n");
    printf("Introducir elemento (2) \n)");
    printf("Eliminar elemento (3) \n");
    printf("Terminar programa (4) \n");

    printf("Seleccione accion: ");
    scanf("%i",&accion);
    switch(accion){
        case 1:
            pintastack(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 2:
            introduce(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 3:
            eliminar(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("Terminando programa");
        break;
        default:
            ("\n Orden no reconocida");
        }
        printf("accion: %i \n",accion);
    }

    printf("Programa terminado");
}
```

Aún así el código tiene problemas, ya que la posición quedará en `0`, esto se debe porque estas pasando la variable `posicion` por valor.

Hay dos posibles soluciones:

- Convertir el primer parámetro de la función `introduce` a puntero, para poder alterar el contenido de la variable `posicion` (la del *main*).
- Agregar un miembro adicional a la estructura `stack` en la cual se encargue de guardar la posición actual del elemento.

Me parece más sencillo la segunda solución:

```c
struct stack
{
    int elemento[max];
    int posicion;
};

typedef struct stack st;

void introduce(st *puntero)
{
    int nelemento;
    if(puntero->posicion < max){
        printf("\n Introduce nuevo elemento: ");
        scanf("%i",&nelemento);
        printf("eco \n");
        puntero->elemento[puntero->posicion]=nelemento;
        printf("ecoo \n");
        puntero->posicion++;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Stack lleno \n");
    }
}
```

**Nota:** Como la función nunca retorna ningún valor, he cambiado de `int` a `void`.

Esta solución aplica también para las demás funciones como `eliminar` y `pintarstack`.

La forma de invocar la función sería así:

```c
int main(void)
{
    st myStack;
    st *puntero = &myStack;
    //Inicializamos la variable "posición"
    puntero->posicion = 0;
    while(accion!=4){
    printf("Lista de opciones: \n");
    printf("Mostrar stack (1) \n");
    printf("Introducir elemento (2) \n)");
    printf("Eliminar elemento (3) \n");
    printf("Terminar programa (4) \n");

    printf("Seleccione accion: ");
    scanf("%i",&accion);
    switch(accion){
        case 1:
            pintastack(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 2:
            introduce(puntero);
        break;
        case 3:
            eliminar(posicion,puntero);
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("Terminando programa");
        break;
        default:
            ("\n Orden no reconocida");
        }
        printf("accion: %i \n",accion);
    }

    printf("Programa terminado");
    return 0;
}
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** La función `crearStack` la puedas eliminar, ya que no hace nada prácticamente.

**2.-** Según el estándar, la función `main` debe estar definido así:

```c
int main(void)
{ 
   //mycode
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hay más de un problema en este código. Por ejemplo, `introduce(posicion,puntero);` --- ¿debería esto cambiar la posición, y cómo debería suceder?